# How to injects ZeppelinContext as variable 'z' in your scala/python environment in Zeppelin?

Tags: java, hadoop, scale, apache-zeppelin, bigdata

Who can tell me the zeppelin how to injects ZeppelinContext as variable 'z' in your scala/python environment in Zeppelin,I want to know it's Internal principle。

Answer (score 0):

z is automatically injected by Zeppelin. If you write code directly in Zeppelin notebook, both in pyspark & spark

If you wanna pass the ZeppelinContext z to other user library, then you need use code like this.

```
userLibrary(z)
```